# How to prevent knockout from stripping empty text nodes from IE8 span siblings

Tags: html, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8, whitespace, knockout-2.0

Say I have 3 spans wrapped in a div.

```
<div>
    <span>1/1/2000</span>
    <span>-</span>
    <span>1/2/2000</span>
</div>
```

Browsers are supposed to interpret the newlines between the spans as whitespace so that the resultant display looks like this:

```
1/1/2000 - 1/2/2000
```

... not like any of these

```
1/1/2000-1/2/2000
1/1/2000- 1/2/2000
1/1/2000 -1/2/2000
```

... and this is the case with IE8 when the spans have no knockout bindings. If you were to inspect the above markup using IE8 Developer tools, you can clearly see "*Text - Empty Text Node*" after each span.

```
<div>
    <span>1/1/2000</span>
    Text - Empty Text Node
    <span>-</span>
    Text - Empty Text Node
    <span>1/2/2000</span>
    Text - Empty Text Node
</div>
```

However, as soon as I put knockout binding on the spans like so, the empty text node behavior changes:

```
<div>
    <span data-bind="text: start"></span>
    <span data-bind="visible: end">-</span>
    Text - Empty Text Node
    <span data-bind="text: end"></span>
    Text - Empty Text Node
</div>
```

... the empty text node between the first 2 spans looks like it's getting stripped. Is this a knockout bug? Any workaround? This is using version 2.3.0.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a fiddle?

Comment: It might just be a typo but <span data-bind-"visible: end">-</span> is not using the '=' attribute. It is using the -????

Comment: @PWKad I was going to try to, but jsfiddle.net threw all kinds of errors in IE8 just trying to create a new fiddle.

Comment: @segFault, no, that was just a typo in my question, I fixed it, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue with whitespaces described in [knockout::text-binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html) documentation (see *Note 4*, may be your IE has *Quirk mode : ON*).
Knockout's solution is to put something to `span`.

```
<div>
    <span data-bind="text: start">&nbsp;</span>
    <span data-bind="visible: end">-</span>
    <span data-bind="text: end">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Also, you can use single `span` element for it:

```
<div>
    <span data-bind="text: start + (end ? ' - ' : '') + end"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: The first line in the HTML is `<!DOCTYPE html>`, so I don't think IE8 is being thrown into quirks mode. Your second suggestion was my temporary workaround, but I did not like it. The first suggestion of putting a non breaking space in the span works too, and though I don't like it either, it's much better than the second option. Is there anything else that could be going on here to cause this?

Comment: @danludwig I havn't more ideas, why IE works unpredictable. IE is crazy